# Get data from JSON file and display it in a REACT component dynamically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, axios, fetch

I'm new to programming and making a carousel with Bootstrap and React. I need the Carousel images to be dynamic and this must be done through a local .json file. This is what I tried but it gives me an error. If you can help me I appreciate it

Slide Component

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const Slide = () => {
  const [datos, setDatos] = useState([]);

  const {
    title1,
    paragraph1,
    img1,
    title2,
    paragraph2,
    img2,
    title3,
    paragraph3,
    img3
  } = datos;

  useEffect(() => {
    const consultApi = async () => {
      const url = 'http://localhost:3000/';
      const results = await axios.get(url);
      setDatos(results.data[0]);
    };
    consultApi();
  }, []);

  //this is another solution but it must be through axios or fetch
  //TODO src={dataV.header.map((img) => img.img1)}
  //TODO src={dataV.header.map((img) => img.img2)}
  //TODO src={dataV.header.map((img) => img.img3)}

  return (
    <>
      <section className="banner">
        <div className="imagenes">
          <div
            id="carouselExampleIndicators"
            className="carousel slide"
            data-bs-ride="carousel"
          >
            <div className="carousel-inner">
              <div className="carousel-item active" data-bs-interval="3000">
                <img src={img1} className="d-block w100" alt="slider1" />
                <div className="carousel-caption container">
                  <h5>{title1}</h5>
                  <p>{paragraph1}</p>
                  <a href="/">Read More</a>
                  <div className="carousel-indicators">
                    <button
                      type="button"
                      data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"
                      data-bs-slide-to={0}
                      className="indicador active"
                      aria-current="true"
                      aria-label="Slide 1"
                    />
                    <button
                      className="indicador"
                      type="button"
                      data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"
                      data-bs-slide-to={1}
                      aria-label="Slide 2"
                    />
                    <button
                      className="indicador"
                      type="button"
                      data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"
                      data-bs-slide-to={2}
                      aria-label="Slide 3"
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="carousel-item" data-bs-interval="3000">
                <img src={img2} className="d-block w100" alt="slider1" />
                <div className="carousel-caption container">
                  <h5>{title2}</h5>
                  <p>{paragraph2}</p>
                  <a href="/">Read More</a>
                  <div className="carousel-indicators">
                    <button
                      type="button"
                      data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"
                      data-bs-slide-to={0}
                      className="indicador"
                      aria-current="true"
                      aria-label="Slide 1"
                    />
                    <button
                      type="button"
                      data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"
                      data-bs-slide-to={1}
                      className="indicador active"
                      aria-label="Slide 2"
                    />
                    <button
                      type="button"
                      data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"
                      data-bs-slide-to={2}
                      className="indicador"
                      aria-label="Slide 3"
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="carousel-item" data-bs-interval="3000">
                <img src={img3} className="d-block w100" alt="slider1" />
                <div className="carousel-caption container">
                  <h5>{title3}</h5>
                  <p>{paragraph3}</p>
                  <a href="/">Read More</a>
                  <div className="carousel-indicators">
                    <button
                      type="button"
                      data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"
                      data-bs-slide-to={0}
                      className="indicador"
                      aria-current="true"
                      aria-label="Slide 1"
                    />
                    <button
                      type="button"
                      data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"
                      data-bs-slide-to={1}
                      className="indicador"
                      aria-label="Slide 2"
                    />
                    <button
                      type="button"
                      data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"
                      data-bs-slide-to={2}
                      className="indicador active"
                      aria-label="Slide 3"
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </>
  );
};

export default Slide;
```

db.json (JSON file that I need to get the data dynamically)

```
    {
  "header": [
    {
      "title1": "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus",
      "paragraph1": "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque.",
      "img1": "img/slide1.png",
      "title2": "Proin elementum massa et felis",
      "paragraph2": "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque.",
      "img2": "img/slide2.png",
      "title3": "Nulla rhoncus vulputate congue",
      "paragraph3": "Aenean rutrum eros nec lacus vehicula, sempler euismod dui.",
      "img3": "img/slide3.png"
    }
  ],
  "about": [
    {
      "principal": "About us",
      "secundario": "We Help Businesses",
      "paragraph": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat.",
      "button": "More info",
      "img": "img/about.png"
    }
  ],
  "services": [
    {
      "titleS": "Services",
      "descS": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras vel gravida felis, id tempor ex. Suspendisse congue purus eu neque auctor, eget dictum ipsum facilisis. Sed scelerisque sodales lorem,",
      "img1": "img/mundo.svg",
      "paragraph1": "Stet clita kasd gubergren",
      "img2": "img/arriba.svg",
      "paragraph2": "At vero eos et accusam",
      "img3": "img/llamar.svg",
      "paragraph3": "Sed ut perspiciatis unde",
      "img4": "img/llamar.svg",
      "paragraph4": "Sed ut perspiciatis unde"
    }
  ],
  "products": [
    {
      "titleP": "Products",
      "descP": "In eget tortor tempor mollis purus",
      "title1": "Aliquam at dui lorem ipsum",
      "list1": "Ut mattis gravida efficitur.",
      "list2": "Ut feugiat vehicula nibh, efficitur laoreet justo.",
      "list3": "Molestie id. Integer varius enim sit amet egestas.",
      "list4": "Ut mattis gravida efficitur"
    }
  ],
  "details": [
    {
      "title": "More details",
      "descD": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras vel gravida felis, id tempor ex. Suspendisse congue purus eu neque auctor, eget dictum ipsum facilisis. Sed scelerisque sodales lorem,",
      "img1": "img/ancla.svg",
      "paragraph1": "Donec egestas tortor quis turpis finibus vestibulum vel nec ex. Nunc sed velit ullamcorper.",
      "img2": "img/campana.svg",
      "paragraph2": "Donec egestas tortor quis turpis finibus vestibulum vel nec ex. Nunc sed velit ullamcorper.",
      "img3": "img/marcador.svg",
      "paragraph3": "Donec egestas tortor quis turpis finibus vestibulum vel nec ex. Nunc sed velit ullamcorper.",
      "img4": "img/rectangulo.svg",
      "paragraph4": "Donec egestas tortor quis turpis finibus vestibulum vel nec ex. Nunc sed velit ullamcorper.",
      "img5": "img/pincel.svg",
      "paragraph5": "Donec egestas tortor quis turpis finibus.",
      "img6": "img/caja.svg",
      "paragraph6": "Donec egestas tortor quis turpis finibus vestibulum vel nec ex. Nunc sed velit ullamcorper."
    }
  ]
}
```

[image: directory]

[image: Errors]

Comment: The error message is a 404 Not Found. I don't know what you think we've supposed to do with that. We have no idea how your server decides what it should serve up when asked for `/`.

Comment: You are requesting the file http://localhost:3000/ by using await axios.get(url). You said it's a local file, so you should be fetching it using '/file.json' instead. Also do not use the port 3000 within your code to refer to the current website.

Comment: @Quentin sorry but as I said I'm new and I have errors.

Comment: @Pascal I tried putting const url = '../../../data/db.json'; and then pass it in get(url) but it keeps giving me an error

Answer (score -1):

First of all, React executes JS file without useEffect. Then, executes useEffect. Lastly, executes JS file. When datos equals to empty array, you cant fetch titles, paragraps and images. You have to remove this line. Also, you can use conditionally rendering in return statement. As an example if datos.length not equal 0 give me page else null. In first rendering, gives null but after useEffect it gives page (see also https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-else-with-conditional-operator)

Additionally, if you created these JSONs, you should refactor like that header: [ {titles1, paragraphs1, images1 }, {titles2, paragraphs2, images2 } ... ].
Through this structure, you can use a loop in return statement with using map function. (see also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: It was one of the first things I tried but it didn't work.

Comment: It is already in data directory. Why do you use axios? Just import it

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @AliKonuk I know that it is in the directory but it is a mandatory requirement that it be done with fetch or axios and in this case I chose axios.